# how can I restrict the top level keys of a heavily nested object?

Tags: typescript

I have a nested object such as:

```
{ 
  'a': { 123: { 'XYZ': { name: 'thing' } } },
  'b': { 456: { 'ZZZ': { name: 'other thing' } } },
}
```

I want to apply restrictions such that the top level keys can only be 'a' or 'b', the 2nd level object's keys can only be numbers, the 3rd level object's keys can only be strings, and the values of that inner object is an object conforming to a specific interface.

I tried doing:

```
interface Item {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
type ValidKeys = 'a' | 'b';

let items = { [index: ValidKeys] : ([index: number] : ([index : string] : Item)) } = {};
```

But `[index: ValidKeys]` is not allowed, and gives me

> An index signature parameter type cannot be a literal type or generic type. Consider using a mapped object type instead.

How can I limit the allowed keys of the top level object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `in` keyword should do it:

```
let items = { [index in ValidKeys]
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=8&ssc=14&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJKQLbIN4FgBQyywAJgFzIgCuGARtANwFEhwYQUDOYUoA5k3wBfAmACeABxQA1OABtSAaQhjOyALzIA5HC3IAPttpbBBORDDFMnCtmQBtUCQgAPYiGSyFJZaoC6yFw8-MhCGjjauoHaAIwATADMWgA0BFrG0VqJACxaQgxAA) with simpler object

**EDIT:** [Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwJYBMDSEQGcoF4oDkcBUAPoQEYEDcAsAFCiRQByArgLYUQBOGIAeQoArCAGNgeKAG8GUKAG0kAOxQQAHgC4oyztx4BdKNtn15S1Ru1ZgPFQHMDJuVFTbdXXnTM64HCNa2Dt4Avgxh9CHeDAgQkkjAEBxYJooqauquyrCIqPxYBgD8xqx6vPxCohJQIVLSUQwJSVgKRARG+NJQAIwATADMqUQUYgSpblAAnNMANL7+2gQUAPZUNesN9GLLyljLsQB0CMv2ABRNyQCU1EA) with lesser types

Comment: that does not seem to work... https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJKQLbIN4FgBQyywAJgFzIgCuGARtANwFEhwYQUDOYUoA5k3wBfAmACeABxQA1OABtSAaQhjOyALzIA5HC3IAPttpbBBORDDFMnCtmQBtUCQgAPYiGSyFJZaoC6yBQAFI4gzi4U1HTQAcGh4YHI3LwgfLFomACUmchCgsDW9jpaAZp2AIwATADMttouYgBeWnWkFOUANJRsHNpyAPZyekK5uQxAA

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=8&ssc=14&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJKQLbIN4FgBQyywAJgFzIgCuGARtANwFEhwYQUDOYUoA5k3wBfAmACeABxQA1OABtSAaQhjOyALzIA5HC3IAPttpbBBORDDFMnCtmQBtUCQgAPYiGSyFJZaoC6yFw8-MhCGjjauoHaAIwATADMWgA0BFrG0VqJACxaQgxAA please check this link with a simple object first

Comment: A lot seems to be happening in your code. if you can simplify `([index: number] : ([index : string] : Item))` what this means

Comment: You have not defined `items` yet. You have just created one variable with no value (declared it).

Comment: You cannot set properties in it

Comment: Ok, I got this working-- https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJKQLbIN4FgBQyywAJgFzIgCuGARtANwFEhwYQUDOYUoA5k3wBfAmACeABxQA1OABtSAaQhjOyALzIA5HC3IAPttpbB4qcgByNelGViA8rQBWEBGA05myANqgSEAA8KajpoAF1kCgBlHn47Rxc3AiFTSRQY3hA+eOdXd008Qh8-QK5YrLCKdAgMZIICOQh3YExOCmxikH8A4hBkWQUSO04wgH5Iy2toHMT3IQ9sFIIWms5vHS0IguQARgAmAGZ27ThaBC1j0goATluAGko2DiMAe2Nkec-BBBeQThfGgA6OQvPgAChWGE4AEoGEA

Is there a way to simplify that so I don't have to declare 3 different types?  Is there a way to do this in one type?

Comment: Only way i think is to use lesser interface/types. But that is worse than what you have right now. Always better to have more types right. You know your data

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwJYBMDSEQGcoF4oDkcBUAPoQEYEDcAsAFCiRQByArgLYUQBOGIAeQoArCAGNgeKAG8GUKAG0kAOxQQAHgC4oyztx4BdKNtn15S1Ru1ZgPFQHMDJuVFTbdXXnTM64HCNa2Dt4Avgxh9CHeDAgQkkjAEBxYJooqauquyrCIqPxYBgD8xqx6vPxCohJQIVLSUQwJSVgKRARG+NJQAIwATADMqUQUYgSpblAAnNMANL7+2gQUAPZUNesN9GLLyljLsQB0CMv2ABRNyQCU1EA

Comment: is the '?' in `{ [index in ValidKeys]? : NumberKeyObject } = {};` the only way to make it valid to assign an empty object?  or is there another way to do that?